# qemu does not display gui that despite passed -display gtk option

Tags: macos, debian, qemu

I want to run debian on qemu on macOS to learn about emulator.

I've installed it with homebrew. 
`brew install qemu --with-vde --with-sdl2 --with-gtk+3 --with-libssh2`
Then I tried run debian on qemu.
But it does not show gui.

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 os.img 6G
qemu-system-x86_64 -display gtk -m 4096 -hda os.img -cdrom debian-9.5.0.iso -boot d
```

How I can run debian with qemu?

- Host: macOS 10.13.6
- Guest: Debian 9.5.0 x86_64
- qemu: 2.12.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to use the GTK UI on OSX. The only supported display option is the default Cocoa one. (Ideally we should make configure not allow you to build the GTK UI, given that it doesn't work.)